# How to combine the two variable and make it as one then assign value to that and get values of for loop out side of the for loop?

Tags: php

Here, I am creating a variable by combining other two variables. After I need to assign value to that. When I print that it should display the 5 times.

for example ,

```
$a='a';
$m=0;
for($b=1;$b<5;$b++){
$a."".$b=$m;
}
```

when I print the $a."".$b out side of the loop it should give me out put like this,

```
a1=0
a2=0 
a3=0
a4=0
```

Then, I want to use this variables for next process. how to do this?
Can any one help me?

Comment: This is probably the time for you to start reading up on arrays. In a couple of minutes, someone will probably post an answer on how you should use `eval()`. Don't take that advice.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment put by Robby.
Sample function would be:

```
    $varArray = array();
    $a='a';
    $m = 0;
    for($b=1;$b<6;$b++){
        $varArray[$a.$b] = $m;
    }
    print_r($varArray);
```

Comment: He said "5 times". You should use <= instead of <

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to code like this

```
$a='a';
$m=0;
$ab = '';
for($b=1;$b<5;$b++){
  $ab .= $a."".$b.'='.$m.'<br>';
}

echo $ab;
```

Comment: Sir then, I need to use that a1 , a2, a3 ,a4 variable separately. How to use that? Then I want to increment the values of those value.If I do a1 ++ it should only increment like this fora2, a3, a4..

Comment: you have to declare these variable first

Comment: Can you reply me soon. I am new to php. I am not getting how to do this.

Comment: Do you mean I need declare as a1, a2, a3 and a4 previously.

Comment: I need to pass $ab means a1 value as array index in my next code. I want to increment it also. Like this I need to do for a2,a3 and a4.

Comment: I am in collage sir. Now, I am not able to skype you sir.